# error file not found with simple example

Tags: errors

I use Miktex 2.9 and Texmaker 5.0.3

I compiled pdflatex and Latex.

No pdf file created (see image): only .aux, .dvi, .log, .tex

Error: File not found with simple code.

Minimal working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hi ABC
\end{document}
```

I compiled with pdflatex, latex but always : file not found.

My log file of PDFLATEX:

```
LOG FILE :



         This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050) (preloaded format=latex 2019.6.23) 23 JUN 2019 15:53
    entering extended mode
    **./testabc.tex
    (testabc.tex
    LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
    ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
    Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
    ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
    File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    )
    \c@part=\count80
    \c@section=\count81
    \c@subsection=\count82
    \c@subsubsection=\count83
    \c@paragraph=\count84
    \c@subparagraph=\count85
    \c@figure=\count86
    \c@table=\count87
    \abovecaptionskip=\skip41
    \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
    \bibindent=\dimen102
    ) (testabc.aux)
    \openout1 = `testabc.aux'.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    [1
    ] (testabc.aux) )
    Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
    202 strings out of 492896
    2428 string characters out of 3130709
    59664 words of memory out of 3000000
    4205 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
    3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
    1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
    23i,4n,17p,133b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
    Output written on testabc.dvi (1 page, 224 bytes)


MY LOG FILE OF LATEX LOG
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050) (preloaded format=latex 2019.6.23) 23 JUN 2019 16:55
entering extended mode
**./testabc.tex
(testabc.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (testabc.aux)
\openout1 = `testabc.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
[1
] (testabc.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
202 strings out of 492896
2428 string characters out of 3130709
59664 words of memory out of 3000000
4205 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
23i,4n,17p,133b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
Output written on testabc.dvi (1 page, 224 bytes).
```

Please help
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Thanks

Comment: With MikTeX and WinEdt as editor I can't reproduce your problem. Also your log file doesn't show any error.

Comment: Zarko, thanks. yeah. i tested in overleaf.com and no error

Comment: what is the actual error message and what file is not found? Your log shows an error free run making a dvi file (not a pdf file) you have not shown any error message so far.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. I compiled pdflatex and Latex. Error message is "File not found".

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by "compiled pdflatex and latex" do you mean you tried both? the log you show is from latex.  That log has no error so when you say you got an error message what program gave an error, your editor? your dvi viewer? what? also I have never seen a system give a file not found error without saying what file it is looking for. _which_ file is not found?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, i have tried pdflatex then latex to compile. Then click "view pdf" and error. I added image above. Thanks

Comment: well if you use latex then click view pdf file not found is expected (that is why I was pushing you to say what you did) latex makes dvi files not pdf files.

Comment: other than that it must be a texmaker configuration issue and I've never seen that editor so I can't help, sorry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank for help. I just added screen of tex maker configuration

Comment: why is latex given just as "latex" so presumably in your path, but pdflatex given by full path name? Also since your screen shots of the error show pdflatex use, it would be good to replace the log you show in the question by the pdflatex log not the latex log

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i added Latex log below PDFLATEX Log. Thanks

Comment: No. you have two latex logs: both say `preloaded format=latex` at the start and `Output written on testabc.dvi` at the end, neither shows a run of pdflatex, and if you have not made a pdf file it is not surprising that the pdf viewer can not show the file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i just checked again. No pdf file created (see image): only .aux, .dvi, .log, .tex created (see attached image above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is misconfigured as David Carlisle has observed. Your editor command for PdfLaTeX should not have a path it should be simply `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` So if pdf generation is not working you will get `file not found` for the pdf step. Wny, Well my guess  is the good old Texmaker is not finding the binaries in the given location. How to rectify for all applications not just this occasion. Do not be tempted as many will advise to simply reconfigure the one entry. Certainly change it back to default (above) and if it works then that is that **(job done)** others should now also work. If it still does not work then the cure is to ensure the correct folder is in the system path at boot time so all applications (not just textmaker) can use them all. I cannot tell exactly where the binary files are but it is likely in your case `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\MiKTeX\bin.`